# Move Root Folder of Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When working on a Mac with Flutter in Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2021.3.1 Patch 4 and XCode 13.1 and/or 13.2):

If you move the root folder of your Flutter project using Finder, then open it in Android Studio and run it, the original folder location is still re-written (multiple sub folders with empty contents, usually, but not always).

Also, the moved project will no longer build from within XCode.

This means that if you don't know the final desired location for your project at the time you create it, you will not be able to move it without weird stuff happening.

How can you move a Flutter project that was created with Android Studio without it having weird side-effects?

More info on how to reproduce:

1. Close all IDEs
2. Open Android Studio
3. Using Android Studio, create a new default FLUTTER project using Java as the Android code choice
4. Using Android Studio, run this project on an Android Emulator
5. Using Android Studio, run this project on an IOS simulator
6. Using Android Studio, open the project in XCode (right-click ios folder and select Flutter\Open project in Xcode)
7. Using XCode, run the project on an IOS simulator

[everything should have worked so far]

8. Close all IDEs
9. Using Finder, move the project folder to a new location that is at the same depth as its current folder, but with a different parent folder.  Meaning if current location is: [root]/x/y/a/my_project_original, the destination would be: [root]/x/y/b/my_project_copy
10. delete the original folder and remember where it was
11. Using Android Studio, open the project from its new location
12. Using Android Studio, open the project in XCode (right-click ios folder and select Flutter\Open project in Xcode)
13. Attempt to run on IOS simulator

[observe error - "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" // "file not found exception"]

14. Using Finder, check to verify original folder location has NOT been re-written
15. Using Android Studio, run the project on Android emulator

[observe that original folder has been re-written!]

Comment: I reproduced your issue with this detailed question. I updated my answer, I was missing a step : removing the .idea file and the build/ folder holding references to your previous path.

Comment: This appears to solve Android Studio's recreation of original folder, but the IOS build error persists (somehow XCode is still getting a reference to the old path from somewhere).  I'll still award you the bounty since this seems to be the best we can get.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I follow to move a project's location on my mac :

- Close your project on Android Studio (File > Close Project)
- Close Android Studio
- Move your project to your new location
- Open Android Studio
- Delete your project from the Recent Projects (on the list of Recent Projects, click on the Settings icon on the right, and "Remove from recent projects")
- Click on "Open" and select your project in the new location.
- Delete the **.idea** file and **build/** folder

The steps should be the same within XCode (in the main window, remove the old location from your recent projects, and Open the new location)

Comment: Are you referring to a Flutter project specifically or just an Android project?  The steps above are what I do also.

Comment: Both since I wrote that you can follow similar steps on Xcode. You can also remove any .idea file from the project and double check that your project isn't storing any absolute paths. I followed the steps written above and succesfully moved a project without any side effect

Answer (score 1):

You can move your Flutter project anywhere, as long as you don't move the files inside the project relative to each other.

**A note about `pod install`**: If you are immediately running from Xcode, you need to run `pod install` inside the `ios` folder after adding a plugin to your `pubspec.yaml`. If you run `flutter run` or use Android Studio to run it, that will run `pod install` for you automatically. However, you don't have to run `pod install` after moving the project, I've just tested it.

> If you move the root folder of your project using Finder, then open it
> in Android Studio and run it, the original folder location is still
> re-written (multiple sub folders with empty contents, usually, but not
> always).

This only happens if you kept Android Studio open when moving the files. You shouldn't open the old project reference in Android Studio, you should open the project using `File` > `Open...`.

> Also, the moved project will no longer build from within Xcode.

If you provide the errors, that will help us help you.

> How can you move a Flutter project that was created with Android Studio without it having weird side-effects?

I have not found any side effects of moving a Flutter project. Quit Android Studio if it is running, and open it using `File` > `Open...`. Or if you are in terminal, run (if installed using Jetbrains toolbox)  `open -a ~/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app/`

Comment: Appreciate your answer and effort.  I've found that "This only happens if you kept Android Studio open" is not true for me, and I've verified the original problem.  I've realized I needed more info in my question, so I added steps to reproduce, and updated my Android Studio version to reflect the problem still exists on patch 4.

Comment: Perhaps after you do the move, you can delete the `.idea` folder in the root project directory while the IDE is not running.